# Internal Server Error on adding ContentNegotiatingViewResolver

Tags: java, spring, maven, http-status-code-500

I have added the 'ContentNegotiatingViewResolver' but after that, I'm getting 500 error. Can you help in getting to what can be wrong?

I already have the `InternalResourceViewResolver` which works fine.

**servlet-config.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <mvc:annotation-driven/>

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.pluralsight.controller"/>

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1"></property>
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager">
      <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager">
        <constructor-arg>
          <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy">
            <constructor-arg>
              <map>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json"></entry>
                <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"></entry>
              </map>
            </constructor-arg>
          </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
      </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultViews">
      <list>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView"></bean>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
          <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
              <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true"></property>
            </bean>
          </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
      </list>
    </property>

  </bean>


  <mvc:resources mapping="/pdfs/**" location="pdfs"/>

  <mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
      p:paramName="language"/>
  </mvc:interceptors>

  <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver"
    p:defaultLocale="en"/>

  <bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
    p:basename="messages"/>

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="2"/>

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" p:order="0"/>
</beans>
```

**web.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
  version="3.1">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/pdfs/**</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fitTrackerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

</web-app>
```

**pom.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.pluralsight</groupId>
  <artifactId>FitnessTracker</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>FitnessTracker Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
      <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Stacktrace of the error** :

```
09-May-2018 15:31:51.413 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'fitTrackerServlet': initialization started
09-May-2018 15:31:51.414 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'fitTrackerServlet-servlet': startup date [Wed May 09 15:31:51 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
09-May-2018 15:31:51.414 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml]
09-May-2018 15:31:51.571 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/addGoal],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.pluralsight.controller.GoalController.updateGoal(com.pluralsight.model.Goal,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
09-May-2018 15:31:51.571 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/addGoal],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.pluralsight.controller.GoalController.addGoal(org.springframework.ui.Model)
09-May-2018 15:31:51.572 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/greeting]}" onto public java.lang.String com.pluralsight.controller.HelloController.sayHello(org.springframework.ui.Model)
09-May-2018 15:31:51.572 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/addMinutes]}" onto public java.lang.String com.pluralsight.controller.MinutesController.addMinutes(com.pluralsight.model.Exercise)
09-May-2018 15:31:51.573 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.register Mapped "{[/activities],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.util.List<com.pluralsight.model.Activity> com.pluralsight.controller.MinutesController.listAllActivities()
09-May-2018 15:31:51.687 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.initControllerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'fitTrackerServlet-servlet': startup date [Wed May 09 15:31:51 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
09-May-2018 15:31:51.712 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.initControllerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'fitTrackerServlet-servlet': startup date [Wed May 09 15:31:51 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
09-May-2018 15:31:51.808 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView#53faebd5' of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView] while setting bean property 'defaultViews' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView#53faebd5' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller#73e1d613' of type [org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller#73e1d613' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/core/ClassLoaderReference
09-May-2018 15:31:51.810 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView#53faebd5' of type [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView] while setting bean property 'defaultViews' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView#53faebd5' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller#73e1d613' of type [org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller#73e1d613' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/core/ClassLoaderReference
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:382)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1531)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:171)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1079)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView#53faebd5' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller#73e1d613' of type [org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller#73e1d613' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/core/ClassLoaderReference
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller#73e1d613' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/core/ClassLoaderReference
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/core/ClassLoaderReference
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.constructXStream(XStreamMarshaller.java:410)
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.buildXStream(XStreamMarshaller.java:398)
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.afterPropertiesSet(XStreamMarshaller.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 52 more
```

Comment: For starters stop mixing jars from spring versions (5.0.4 and 4.3.10) use the same version. You are also mixing jackson versions (1.9.13, 2.6.3 and 2.9.4). So first fix your dependencies. If that doesn't resolve things at least put your stacktrace in your question (the full stacktrace!) so that we can see what the actual exception is.

Comment: @M.Deinum 1).Updated versions of the dependencies to match. 2). Added the complete Stacktrace of the error.

Comment: Spring 4.3 requires Stream 1.4.5 you are including 1.4.4.. I suggest upgrading to the newest 1.4.10. Basically is has nothing to do with the `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Updated the `xstream` version to 1.4.10 and it works. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was using the incompatible versions of the dependencies. Once I updated those this issue was resolved.

Updated `pom.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.pluralsight</groupId>
  <artifactId>FitnessTracker</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>FitnessTracker Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
      <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```